# Dynamic FlexibleHeaderDelegate's expandedHeight base on image height and screen width

Tags: flutter

I am using a SliverPersistentHeader with FlexibleHeaderDelegate. Header Image is upload by user from admin backend. Please see two different screen with different expandedHeight.

250 is shrink because original image's height is bigger than the width. If I put expandedHeight to 500, then image is looking great. The issue here that I have no idea which size of image will user upload. So can I set the image height base on screen width dynamically.

expandedHeight: 250,

[image]

expandedHeight: 500,

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:sliver_header_delegate/sliver_header_delegate.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/blocs/bloc.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/models/models.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

import '../../widgets/circular_progress_indicator_widget.dart';
import '../error/something_went_wrong.dart';

class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/message';
  final String? messageId;
  const MessageScreen({Key? key, this.messageId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessageScreen> createState() => _MessageScreenState();
}

class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
  _loadMessage() async {
    BlocProvider.of<MessageBloc>(context)
        .add(GetMessageEvent(widget.messageId!));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadMessage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: BlocBuilder<MessageBloc, MessageState>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, MessageState state) {
          if (state is MessageError) {
            return SomethingWentWrongScreen(error: state.error);
          } else if (state is MessageLoaded) {
            return CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  floating: false,
                  delegate: FlexibleHeaderDelegate(
                    statusBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                    expandedHeight: 500,
                    background: MutableBackground(
                      collapsedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      expandedWidget: buildImage(context, state.message),
                    ),
                    children: [
                      FlexibleTextItem(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        text: state.message.title,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        collapsedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline2!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                        expandedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline2!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                        expandedAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        collapsedAlignment: Alignment.center,
                        collapsedPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                        expandedPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 16, vertical: 5),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                      child: Html(
                        data: state.message.message,
                        style: {
                          "body": Style(
                              fontSize: const FontSize(18.0),
                              //fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              lineHeight: LineHeight.em(1.5)),
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(BuildContext context, Message message) => AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: message.picture,
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: how about using `BoxFit.cover`

Comment: If I put BoxFit.cover, I can only see one third of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I calculate image and call from future builder.Will add animation for image.

```
Future<Size> calculateImageDimension(Message message) {
    Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
    Image image = Image.network(message.picture);
    image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
      ImageStreamListener(
        (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
          var myImage = image.image;
          Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
          completer.complete(size);
        },
      ),
    );
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
          body: BlocBuilder<MessageBloc, MessageState>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, MessageState state) {
              if (state is MessageError) {
                return SomethingWentWrongScreen(
                    error: state.error, screenName: 'Message Screen');
              } else if (state is MessageLoaded) {
                return FutureBuilder<Size>(
                    future: calculateImageDimension(state.message),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Size> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return CustomScrollView(
                          slivers: [
                            SliverPersistentHeader(
                              pinned: true,
                              floating: false,
                              delegate: FlexibleHeaderDelegate(
                                statusBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                                expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                    snapshot.data!.height /
                                    snapshot.data!.width,
                                background: MutableBackground(
                                  collapsedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  expandedWidget:
                                      buildImage(context, state.message),
                                ),
                                children: [
                                  FlexibleTextItem(
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    text: state.message.title,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    collapsedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .headline2!
                                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                    expandedStyle: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .headline2!
                                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                    expandedAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    collapsedAlignment: Alignment.center,
                                    collapsedPadding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                                    expandedPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 16, vertical: 5),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50),
                                  child: Html(
                                    data: state.message.message,
                                    style: {
                                      "body": Style(
                                          fontSize: const FontSize(18.0),
                                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          lineHeight: LineHeight.em(1.5)),
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
                      }
                    });
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
            },
          ),
        );
      }
```